# Алгоритм движения по координатам

Tags: arduino, gps

Хочу определенное устройство на ардуино заставить двигаться по gps координатам. Возможно есть какие-то проверенные практики для этого.

Сейчас есть такие мысли: вычислить курс по имеющимся координатам(текущая точка и конечная точка), взять этот курс, на борту будет компас, и постоянно корректировать этот курс( раз в секунду).
Буду благодарен за любые мысли/идеи/ссылки

Comment: Ради интереса, о каких масштабах идёт речь? и какой способ передвижения?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Катер 80х16см, масштабы пока в пределах одного водоема

Comment: Водоема категории озеро Байкал или водоема категории карьер с водой? Может случиться так, что погрешность gps будет превышать размеры водоема и получится полная ерунда.

Comment: @Эникейщик, может.